# jQuery UI tabs and deep linking

Tags: jquery, user-interface, jquery-ui-tabs, deep-linking

I used the [BBQ plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-bbq-plugin/) but can't seem to get the URL's as I would like. I want to make the url after the hash reflect the div id, like http://www.example.com/page.php#nodeID instead of http://www.example.com/page.php#parentNode=2 with two being the child node number. Is this possible?

I also tried the [asual address plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) but it only seems to work on remote content. I would like to have all the tabs on one page and not load the content via ajax, is it possible to modify it as such?

thanks to anyone and everyone!